# Figure not showing

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, includegraphics

I am working on my thesis project and want to insert an image. This works fine at first, but I want to use the figure environment to give it a caption. However, when I do this I get ``` signs on the page instead of the figure. Everything else works just fine.

What am I doing wrong? Does it got something to do with a float and a report decument?

This is my preamble:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {C:/Users/beren/Documents/Master SCM/Thesis/Images/} }
\usepackage[a4paper, width=150mm, top = 16mm, bindingoffset=10mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{Topic title}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[LO,CE]{SCM Master Thesis} 
\fancyfoot[CO,RE]{Name}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{References.bib}
%\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge}
```

And this is what my code of my chapter looks like (where I want to insert the picture), so no not in the main.tex file:

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
\tikzstyle{myblock} = [rectangle, draw, minimum height=1cm] 
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (BDA)[myblock]{BDA Capabilities};
    \node (FP)[myblock,right = 0.2cm and 8cm of BDA]{Firm Performance};
    \draw[->] (BDA) -- node[above, yshift = 0.2cm] {+} (FP);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Conceptual model}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[t]
\caption{Simplified model of container flow with three possible decisions at the port to continue}
%\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{Figure1} 
\end{figure}
```

I actually gave it a second attempt to get one of my own figures in Latex as well, but I got the same issue.

Your response is highly appreciated! :-)

Link to figure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dim8u.jpg
Minimum code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {C:/Users/beren/Documents/Master SCM/Thesis/Images/} }
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}





\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
\tikzstyle{myblock} = [rectangle, draw, minimum height=1cm] 
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (BDA)[myblock]{BDA Capabilities};
    \node (FP)[myblock,above right = 0.2cm and 8cm of BDA]{Firm Performance};
    \draw[->] (BDA) -- node[above, yshift = 0.2cm] {+} (FP);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Conceptual model}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[t]
\caption{Simplified model of container flow with three possible decisions at the port to continue}
%\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{Figure1} 
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! `right = 0.2cm and 8cm of BDA` is not correct, do you mean `above right = 0.2cm and 8cm of BDA`? Also, your preamble does not seem to load `tikz`, nor `positioning`, which would be needed here. BTW, `\tikzstyle` is deprecated.

Comment: Please merge your code fragments to one complete small document with your image which we can compile as it is.

Comment: Thank you, I tried it but unfortunately it did not work. You are right, I forgot to mention the preamble code for tikz but in fact I had it in my Latex document.

@Zarko, I put the minimum working code in my question, is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Just to clarify: Is the figure that does not show up the `tikzpicture`or the one added via `\includegraphcis`?

Comment: Via '\Includegraphics'

Comment: Probably the space in your `\graphicspath` is the problem?

Comment: Hi @Fastbanana and welcome to TeX-SE. The most important advice to ask questions here ***and** to solve problems by yourself: Remove non related packages and anything else. See: [I've just been asked to write a minimal working example (MWE), what is that?
](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/140133).

Comment: Thank you leandriis, I tried removing the space in graphics path but I got the same issue.

FHZ, thank you for your reply, I adapted my example. Actually, when I use this minimum working example in a new .tex file I do not have any issues. But the issue remains in the code I wrote.

Comment: That means your example is too minimal. Start with the one that doesn’t work and pare it down.

Comment: Looks like it was a silly solution, a /newpage insert did the trick. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, but I didn't quite understand your request. Are you asking for something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}}      
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 74; green, 144; blue, 226 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=2.25]    (411.53,118) -- (456,90.5) ;
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 74; green, 144; blue, 226 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=2.25]  (87,130.97) .. controls (87,123.81) and (92.81,118) .. (99.97,118) -- (229.53,118) .. controls (236.69,118) and (242.5,123.81) .. (242.5,130.97) -- (242.5,169.89) .. controls (242.5,177.05) and (236.69,182.86) .. (229.53,182.86) -- (99.97,182.86) .. controls (92.81,182.86) and (87,177.05) .. (87,169.89) -- cycle ;
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 74; green, 144; blue, 226 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=2.25]  (269,130.97) .. controls (269,123.81) and (274.81,118) .. (281.97,118) -- (411.53,118) .. controls (418.69,118) and (424.5,123.81) .. (424.5,130.97) -- (424.5,169.89) .. controls (424.5,177.05) and (418.69,182.86) .. (411.53,182.86) -- (281.97,182.86) .. controls (274.81,182.86) and (269,177.05) .. (269,169.89) -- cycle ;
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 74; green, 144; blue, 226 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=2.25]  (452,40.97) .. controls (452,33.81) and (457.81,28) .. (464.97,28) -- (594.53,28) .. controls (601.69,28) and (607.5,33.81) .. (607.5,40.97) -- (607.5,79.89) .. controls (607.5,87.05) and (601.69,92.86) .. (594.53,92.86) -- (464.97,92.86) .. controls (457.81,92.86) and (452,87.05) .. (452,79.89) -- cycle ;
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 74; green, 144; blue, 226 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=2.25]  (452,130.97) .. controls (452,123.81) and (457.81,118) .. (464.97,118) -- (594.53,118) .. controls (601.69,118) and (607.5,123.81) .. (607.5,130.97) -- (607.5,169.89) .. controls (607.5,177.05) and (601.69,182.86) .. (594.53,182.86) -- (464.97,182.86) .. controls (457.81,182.86) and (452,177.05) .. (452,169.89) -- cycle ;
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 74; green, 144; blue, 226 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=2.25]  (452,219.97) .. controls (452,212.81) and (457.81,207) .. (464.97,207) -- (594.53,207) .. controls (601.69,207) and (607.5,212.81) .. (607.5,219.97) -- (607.5,258.89) .. controls (607.5,266.05) and (601.69,271.86) .. (594.53,271.86) -- (464.97,271.86) .. controls (457.81,271.86) and (452,266.05) .. (452,258.89) -- cycle ;
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 74; green, 144; blue, 226 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=2.25]    (242,151) -- (268,151.5) ;
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 74; green, 144; blue, 226 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=2.25]    (425,151) -- (453,151.5) ;
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 74; green, 144; blue, 226 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=2.25]    (457,209.5) -- (411.53,182.86) ;
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 74; green, 144; blue, 226 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=2.25]    (89,303) -- (605,299.53) ;
\draw [shift={(610,299.5)}, rotate = 539.62] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 74; green, 144; blue, 226 }  ,fill opacity=1 ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (14.29,-6.86) -- (0,0) -- (14.29,6.86) -- cycle    ;
\draw (164.75,150.43) node   [align=left] {BDA Capabilities};
% Text Node
\draw (346.75,150.43) node   [align=left] {Firm Performance};
% Text Node
\draw (486,59) node   [align=left] {text 1};
% Text Node
\draw (486,148) node   [align=left] {text 2};
% Text Node
\draw (488,238) node   [align=left] {text 3};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Conceptual model}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, you put a lot of effort in this. Thank you! My issue was that the figure(s) did not show up, but adding /newpage solved the issue. I will take your input into account for my thesis, probably very useful at some point in time. :-)

Comment: @Fastbanana Actually I have used Mathcha.io a very fast editor to draw in TikZ. :-) You, however, always follow the advice of the best users who follow the correct rules of the code to be used in TikZ.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear, what is your problem, especially because You stated in your comment, that it is solved by inserting `/newpage` in your code (where?) ...

Let me emphasized, that for helping you it is crucial, that you provide MWE (Minimal Working Example), which reproduce your problem. In the most of times happens, that in it preparation you discover error yourself. It is also important for other members of site, that they can compare own similar problems and see if proposed solutions also works for them.

Assuming, that `\graphicspath` is correctly defined and that it lead to folder, where is image stored and that image is in it, than the next suggestion can be possible solution.

Suggestion also contain off-topic proposal how to simply draw your TikZ picture with help of the `forest` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{forest}
for tree = {
% nodes style
          draw = cyan, rounded corners, ultra thick,
minimum height = 1cm,
    text width = 32mm, align=left,
% tree style
        grow' = 0,
 child anchor = west,
         edge = {thick, cyan},
        s sep = 3mm,
        l sep = 6mm,
            }
[BDA Capabilities, name=root
    [Firm Performance
        [text 1]
        [text 2]
        [text 3, name=leaf3]
    ]
]
\coordinate[below=3mm of leaf3.south east] (aux);
\path[draw=cyan, ultra thick,-{Triangle[length=2mm]}]
    (root.west |- aux)  -- (aux);
\end{forest}
    \caption{Conceptual model.}
\label{fig:concept}

\medskip
\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
    \caption{Simplified model of container flow with three possible decisions at the port to continue.}
\label{fig:container}
    \end{figure}
I suppose that figures \ref{fig:concept} and \ref{fig:container} should be one after other closely tied, so I put them in a common float \verb+figure+ with two captions.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Red lines in above image indicate border of text area. It helps to see, that on page is sufficient space for both figures (in common float).